# How to modify zend Db_RecordExists validator where clause?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I want to add check for more than one values in where clause. Db_RecordExists just check for one filed. I have read that you can extend zend validate abstract class and you can have your own validator. can I have one little example about this please.

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? To me, you don't even need a custom validator.

If you read carefully the source code of `Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract` you will notice this phpDoc above the constructor:

> Provides basic configuration for use with Zend_Validate_Db Validators
>   Setting $exclude allows a single record to be excluded from matching.
>   Exclude can either be a String containing a where clause, or an array with `field` and `value` keys
>   to define the where clause added to the sql.
>   A database adapter may optionally be supplied to avoid using the registered default adapter.
>
> ### The following option keys are supported:
>
> 1. 'table'   => The database table to validate against
> 2. 'schema'  => The schema keys
> 3. 'field'   => The field to check for a match
> 4. 'exclude' => An optional where clause or field/value pair to exclude from the query
> 5. 'adapter' => An optional database adapter to use

Which means that if you want to check if a record exists using more than one value, you can do it simply in **passing the where clause to the validator** instead of a pair field/value:

```
$where = 'user_id != 110 AND email != "email@example.com"';
$where = array('users', 'email', $where);

$element->addValidator('db_NoRecordExists', true, $where)
```

This will basically check if a record exists in the *users* table, and exclude rows where  *user id != 110* or *email@example.com*. Naturally, I recommend you to use [Zend_Db methods](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.update) such as `quoteIdentifier()` in order to generate a fully escaped query expression.

You can add as many fields as you want of course.

You can find [more information about `Db_NoRecordExists` in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db).

Comment: thank you. I was hoping your answer here. Please spare some time for me. I want to know about Bootstrap.php. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Liyali I want user entered password to match against hashed password in table. How to do it?

Comment: Since you did not indicate where you want to do this, and I presume you don't want to do it in a form validator, so you can use `Zend_Auth` ;) [Read more about it here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html).

Answer (score 1):

All you usually have to do is override the isValid() method to make a custom validator,
 here is an example of a custom validator:

```
<?php

class My_Validator_Usphone extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {
    const PHONE = 'phone';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::PHONE => "'%value%' is not a valid U.S. phone number.
            Phone number must be entered in (xxx)xxx-xxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx format."
    );

    public function isValid($value) {
        $this->_setValue($value);

        $isValid = TRUE;
        $pattern = ('/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/');
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
            $this->_error(self::PHONE);
            $isValid = FALSE;
        }
        return $isValid;
    }
```

}

Db_RecordExists is pretty simple but it extends `Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract` and should be pretty easy to modify to validate against two fields, but you may have to override `isValid()` and `getSelect()` or `_query()` to accept more then one value.

```
class Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists extends Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $valid = true;
        $this->_setValue($value);

        $result = $this->_query($value);
        if (!$result) {
            $valid = false;
            $this->_error(self::ERROR_NO_RECORD_FOUND);
        }

        return $valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have three questions 1. Where to put this class in zend structure? 2. I am using a form by extending zend form. So how to use it there? 3. Once form is post how can I pass required values to this class? Thank you for your time and help.