# Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists exclude logic issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I've got a form for a job application, where administrator needs to pick from the list of certain user ids. The list contains only user ids of type "employer", however I want to validate the administrator input, so if he manually inserts an id that doesn't exist or is for user of different type than "employer", the validation should fail. I thought that code to do this would be:

```
new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'id',
        'exclude' => "mode != 'employer'"
    )
)
```

so, I'm searching for all the records in table users, excluding those where mode != 'employer' - if such record exists, where id is equal to the one picked from input, it passes the validation. However, the code above doesn't work - I have to do `'exclude' => "mode = 'employer'"`, so exclude actually equals where statement. My understanding of the logic here is wrong - can somebody tell me why?

PHP: 5.2.17, Zend: 1.10.4

EDIT: (the comment to @ro ko enquiries, as it probably clears things out)

Please find the table and sample code here: http://pastebin.com/C7AXMNTZ . In my understanding this should return valid for Joker (is employer), but false for Kingpin (not employer) and Poison Ivy (not in the db) - as you can see the results are not what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation (search for `The above example will check the table to ensure no records other than the one where id = $user_id contains the value $username.`) the exclude option indeed works as WHERE statement.

I can only say that whoever though that using such keyword for this functionality is a good idea had a wicked sense of humor.

Answer (score 2):

**A) `'exclude' => "mode != 'employer'"`**

```
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("id");
    $id->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
    $id->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'villains',
        'field' => 'id',
        'exclude' => "mode != 'employer'"
    )));
```

Produces the following query:

```
SELECT `villains`.`id` 
    FROM `villains` 
    WHERE (`id` = :value) AND (mode != 'employer') 
    LIMIT 1
```

**B) `'exclude' => "mode = 'employer'"`**

```
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("id");
    $id->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
    $id->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'villains',
        'field' => 'id',
        'exclude' => "mode = 'employer'"
    )));
```

Produces the following query:

```
SELECT `villains`.`id` 
    FROM `villains` 
    WHERE (`id` = :value) AND (mode = 'employer') 
    LIMIT 1
```

**C) `'exclude' => array("field" => "mode", "value" => "employer")`**

```
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("id");
    $id->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
    $id->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'villains',
        'field' => 'id',
        'exclude' => array(
            "field" => "mode",
            "value" => "employer"
        )
    )));
```

Produces the following query:

```
SELECT `villains`.`id` 
    FROM `villains` 
    WHERE (`id` = :value) AND (`mode` != 'employer') 
    LIMIT 1
```

## Outcomes

You want **B**. It *is* confusing and arguably the logic and behaviour of the component is backwards. Nonetheless, the behaviour you want is from example B.

## Appendix

We can hack a test (and I really mean hack together) to check that the above works as expected.

Both test1 and test2 pass, but as you can see from the providers, they both produce different results.

```
class SO14706653Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Connection
     */
    public $dbConnection;

    public function getRowCount($tableName) {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$this->dbConnection->quoteSchemaObject($tableName);
        return (int) $this->dbConnection->getConnection()->query($query)->fetchColumn();
    }

    // hack a very quick setup for tests
    public function setup() {
        $app = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        $app->bootstrap();
        $dbAdapter = $app->getBootstrap()->getResource('db'); /* @var $db Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */
        $this->dbConnection = new Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Connection($dbAdapter, 'unittests');

        $dbAdapter->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `villains` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
              `mode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");

        $dbAdapter->exec('DELETE FROM villains'); // clean out db data

        $dbAdapter->exec("
            INSERT INTO `villains` VALUES(1, 'Joker', 'employer');
            INSERT INTO `villains` VALUES(2, 'Kingpin', '');
            INSERT INTO `villains` VALUES(3, 'Penguin', '');
        ");
    }

    // ensure the above setup is working as expected
    public function assertPreConditions() {
        $this->assertEquals(3, $this->getRowCount('villains')); 
    }

    public function provideTest1()
    {
        return [
            // form data        is valid?       isRequired?
            [['id' => '1'],     false,          false],
            [['id' => '2'],     true,           false],
            [['id' => '3'],     true,           false],
            [['id' => ''],      true,           false],
            [[],                true,           false],
            [['id' => '856'],   false,          false],
            [['id' => '856'],   false,          true],
            [['id' => ''],      false,          true],
            [[],                false,          true],
        ];
    }

    public function provideTest2()
    {
        return [
            //  form data       is valid?       isRequired?
            [['id' => '1'],     true,           false],
            [['id' => '2'],     false,          false],
            [['id' => '3'],     false,          false],
            [['id' => ''],      true,           false],
            [[],                true,           false],
            [['id' => '856'],   false,          false],
            [['id' => '856'],   false,          true],
            [['id' => ''],      false,          true],
            [[],                false,          true],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider provideTest1
     */
    public function test1(array $data, $isValid, $isRequired)
    {
        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("id");
        $id->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
        $id->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
            'table' => 'villains',
            'field' => 'id',
            'exclude' => "mode != 'employer'"
        )));
        $id->setRequired($isRequired);
        $form->addElement($id);

        // produces the query
        // SELECT `villains`.`id`
        // FROM `villains`
        // WHERE (`id` = :value) AND (mode != 'employer')
        // LIMIT 1

        $this->assertSame($isValid, $form->isValid($data));
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider provideTest2
     */
    public function test2(array $data, $isValid, $isRequired)
    {
        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("id");
        $id->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
        $id->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(array(
            'table' => 'villains',
            'field' => 'id',
            'exclude' => "mode = 'employer'"
        )));
        $id->setRequired($isRequired);
        $form->addElement($id);

        // produces the query
        // SELECT `villains`.`id` 
        // FROM `villains` 
        // WHERE (`id` = :value) AND (mode = 'employer') 
        // LIMIT 1

        $this->assertSame($isValid, $form->isValid($data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass an array in the exclude option. Eg.

```
$this->getElement('username')->addValidator(
    new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
        array(
        'table' => 'user', 
        'field' => 'username', 
        'exclude' => array(
                'field' => 'username', 
                'value' => $username
            )
        )
    )
);
```

[Check here for more info.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db)

Edit: After reading the question again, I see I didn't actually answer it. The only other advice I would give is using the quoteInto statement as in the documentation.

```
$email     = 'user@example.com';
$clause    = $db->quoteInto('email != ?', $email);
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'username',
        'exclude' => $clause
    )
);
```

Also here is a link to another question about Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExistswhich has a very good answer.

[How to modify zend Db_RecordExists validator where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529500/how-to-modify-zend-db-recordexists-validator-where-clause)

Comment: Excuse me, but how does that answer my question?

Comment: I mean - I can use a clause, as per `You can also provide a string to the exclude clause so you can use an operator other than !=`

Comment: no change. If I'm not mistaken, the use of quoteInto shouldn't reduce any different results, as it's to escape any quotes (was worth a try though, maybe it's a bug that's affecting strings and not objects - ie. PDO statement, dunno)

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused here. Logic is fine with the validator.

> How? 
>   Well exclude here adds negation to your condition.

```
'exclude' => "mode = 'employer'"
```

OR

```
'exclude' => array(
                'field' => 'mode', 
                'value' => 'employer'
            )
```

is interpreted as validator should stand valid for other than `mode = employer` condition.

**EDIT:** If you see [In the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db) you'll see a description: "The above example will check the table to ensure no records other than the one where id = $user_id contains the value $username." this statement should clear things for you I assume.

Comment: But I want it to stand valid only for the rows, where mode = 'employer' (so, exclude all the rows where mode != 'employer'). Yes, I'm confused :)

Comment: Additionally - `exclude: Sets records which will be excluded from the search.` - thus my initial `mode != 'employer'` should work, as I don't want these rows to be taken into consideration. Please, don't tell me it's a bug with my version of Zend...

Comment: @eithed could you add actual data set and you're expected result set and I'll try to make an explanation on it + others might also be able to make it more clear perhaps.

Comment: I am having a feeling that you are comparing the logic for Db_NoRecordExists in your case.

Comment: please find the table and sample code here: http://pastebin.com/C7AXMNTZ . In my understanding this should return valid for Joker (is employer), but false for Kingpin (not employer) and Poison Ivy (not in the db) - as you can see the results are not what I'm expecting. 

Well, I wasn't mentioning anything about NoRecordExists :D my question is purely about this validator, though exclude option is the same for both validators.